# CkEditor Dialog Event Handling

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I've just started to use CKEditor and I can't manage to understand the API well enough to accomplish what I am aiming for.

Essentially, I have a few instances of the editor on the page. However, for the editor by the name of htmlInput, I want to collect the names of the form elements that are added to the editor. The closest I've gotten is to have an alert pop up when the appropriate dialogs are opened, but I haven't been able to extract the value of the name field of these boxes.

Here's what I have so far.

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (e) {
    var dialogName = e.data.name;
    var dialog = e.data.definition.dialog;

    if(e.editor.name == 'htmlInput' && (dialogName=='checkbox' || dialogName=='radio' || dialogName=='textfield' || dialogName == 'textarea' || dialogName == 'select'))
    {
        dialog.on('show', function (ev) {
            alert('here');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is very unsafe. Imagine what if someone pasted such form element or used `editor.insertHtml()` method. They won't be collected. The better approach is as follows:

```
var form = {};

CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
    elements: {
        $: function( element ) {
            if ( element.name in { 'input' : 1, 'textarea': 1, 'button' : 1 } ) {
                if ( !form[ element.name ] )
                    form[ element.name ] = [];

                form[ element.name ].push( element );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now when you can basically do the following:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
console.log( form );
```

Then you'll retrieve all the form elements (or elements of any kind) that belong to the document. Just make sure your `form` object is empty when serializing forms since i.e. `htmlFilter` is also executed when switching between souce mode <-> wysiwyg and it will continuously populate your list.

---

You can also basically use the following to retrieve elements by tag name (simple way IMO):

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getElementsByTag( 'input' );
```

Comment: How do I get about retrieving the element names?. For instance if there were an element <input type="text" name="test" value="test2" />, I can get the value by using element.attributes.value. When I type element.name I get 'input' and when I type element.attributes.name I get undefined. How would I go about retrieving the string 'test'?

Comment: Hmm.. I see it working a little bit, but still having issues. For example, the primary case(s) I've seen it not working is when you use the form element buttons provided as part of CKEditor, it doesn't always update, at least it doesn't seem like it to me. I've been using two methods to call the htmlFilter. The first is through the .getData() - this always returns undefined. The second is through switching between source mode and wysiwyg. This calls the htmlFilter each time, but appears to take a couple mode changes to not return undefined. I tried to use the fiddle, with my config

Comment: and so here is using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4sKF/3/) and here is on my site where the button calls the getData() for the [htmlFilter](http://militaryreunionplanners.com/testing.html)